# How to use Or filters for getting data from OLAP cube pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas

We are loading data from an SSAS model (cube) into an Excel pivot table.  The data within the spreadsheet needs to be shown using 2 conditions in OR way, I mean, I have 2 fields coming from the database: Original amount and amendment amount, We need display the information coming from the SSAS cube when original amount <=10.000 OR amendment_amount<=10.000.

I tried to use the normal filters on Excel pivot tables, but it doesn't worked, because filters use AND implicitly to display information, I need OR.

I tried to use the normal filters on Excel pivot tables (value and label filters), but it doesn't worked, because filters use AND implicitly to display information, I need OR.

```
example:
Code    original amount     amendment amount
C1          25000   500
C2          2000    18000
C3          14000   9000
C4          12000   10500
```

Filtering by Original_amount<=10.000  and amendment_amount<=10.000 is noy displaying any records

The result expected is C1,C2 and C3 code records displayed because one og the both conditions is true...
How could I filter for displaying the right data?

Using the example described above, the result expected is C1,C2 and C3 code records displayed because one of both conditions is true...

```
results expected:
Code      original amount    amendment amount
C1        25.000             500
C2         2.000             18.000
C3        14.000             9.000
```

How could I filter for displaying the right data?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [calculated measure](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/10/15/calculated-member-and-measures-in-excel-2013/) in the PivotTable which is called Show Row:

```
IIF(
 (
  Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[original amount]))
  AND [Measures].[original amount] <=10000
 )
 OR 
 (
  Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[amendment amount]))
  AND [Measures].[amendment amount]<=10000
 ),
 1,
 Null
)
```

Then add that calculated measure to your PivotTable and filter to keep only rows where Show Row >= 1.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but unfortunately it seems not working, I created the calculated measure succesfully, but when I try to add it as column to the pivot table, Excel freeze and alter longtime nothing is done - no columm added.  Some idea why it happens?  thanks in advance

Comment: @Mat.B Maybe start with a smaller pivot like one row and 1 column to test your formula?

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try it.  Second question.. I have as well a new field to include in any other excel report. Data is coming from ssas, actually from the same model. 
I am trying to implement in the same way as the calculated measure you mentioned in the answer this time is showing up the column but no with the right results.   This is my calculated measure:

Comment: this is my measure for my second question:      

  IIF(
 (
  Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[Total Contract Amount]))
  AND  [Measures].[Total Contract Amount] <>0
 ),
[PO].[Record Date],
1
)
problem is : when condition is true the information  shown up is only blank spaces, 
 it is not showing the record_date  data, and is  showing up much more records, I mean before to add 
the measure it showed up 5 records, after include the measure it is showing at least 100 records, which is wrong .  
What should I do to solve it?

Comment: @Mat.B what dimension do you have on rows? Something in the PO dimension?